# Getting the data from datatable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

in my web application i am using datatable and inserting outlook contacts in that.
this is my code

```
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = myTable.NewRow();
    DataColumn myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
    myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    myDataColumn.ColumnName = "Email";
    myTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);        

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressList addList in oApp.Session.AddressLists)
    {

        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry addEntry in addList.AddressEntries)
        {
            dr["Email"] = addEntry.Address.ToString();
            myTable.Rows.Add(dr);
            dr = myTable.NewRow();
            //Response.Write(addEntry.Address.ToString());
        }

    }
```

My doubt is can i write the code like this 
when contact is insert into mytable. the details of the row can read into a string like this

string s=  myTable.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString(); in foreach

Comment: Please fix the formatting on your code block.  Much of it is not marked as code.

Comment: Mr.Sam i am sorry i not understand

Comment: Ugh, Office interop in asp.net is evil.  It doesn't scale and is error prone.  You should not do it.  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar enough with outlook to tell you what the correct work-around is.

Comment: Oh, and what is your question?  It's not at clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DataRow collection of the foreach loop and get the corresponding row values.

```
foreach (DataRow dr in myTable.Rows)
{
    // Specify the column name or column index of the datacolumn
    //dr["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

or you can use a DataView of the DataTable and iterate through the DataRowView collection

```
DataView dv = myTable.DefaultView;

foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
{
    drv.Row["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```